# Not equal <> query excludes NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I'm having a problem with some SQL queries that I cant figure out.

```
SELECT * FROM MasterList WHERE Requested <> "Yes";
```

If I run the above query on my table I get 60 records returned. However There should be close to 300.  I think the issue is, some of the records are just blank in the Requested field and others are NULL.  But I would have thought NULL would still count as not equal to "Yes" wouldnt it? If not, is there a way around that without having to go back and 'blank' all the null fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nulls are not counted in comparison, if you want `null` values to be returned then you need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MasterList WHERE Requested <> "Yes" OR Requested IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can build my queries in a way that accounts for NULL.

Answer (score 8):

`<=>`
NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;  
    -> 1, 1, 0   
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;   
    -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

in your case use:

```
SELECT * FROM MasterList WHERE not Requested <=> "Yes"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same issue and someone introduced me to the `IS DISTINCT FROM` construct. Very useful but not available for all DBMS!

```
SELECT * FROM MasterList WHERE Requested IS DISTINCT FROM "Yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `null <> 'Yes'` expression evaluates to `null`, thus you should add a separate `is null` check to include records that meet this condition in your result set:

```
select * from MasterList where Requested <> "Yes" or Requested is null
```

P.S.: comparison of `null` with anything, even with `null` itself, always returns `null`.