# SQL problem: WHERE field="XXX" works, but WHERE field<>"XXX" returns blank table

Tags: sql, ssms

So I've got a query that works fine, but have been asked to add another qualifier to.
We want to remove results that have a certain text in a a certain column. Without this qualifier I get a table that has NULLs and the this text in said column.
Adding
`WHERE field='TEXT'`
Gets me list of just the ones I want to exclude. BUT none of the opposites work.
`WHERE field<>'TEXT'`, `WHERE NOT field='TEXT'`, `WHERE field NOT LIKE 'TEXT'`, and `WHERE field NOT LIKE '%TEXT'` all get me the same thing- a blank table.

can any one help?

Comment: OK, just found an answer in another post: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148150/not-equal-query-excludes-null-values"
 ```and (field<>'TEXT' OR field IS NULL)```

need to do the AND with the OR... This worked!

Still thank you to Caius Jard for helping me understand why my try wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without this qualifier I get a table that has NULLs and the this text in said column

If your table looks like this:

```
Field
TEXT
TEXT
NULL
TEXT
```

Then a WHERE clause of `field = 'TEXT'` will return 3 rows, but a WHERE clause of `field <> 'TEXT'` will correctly return no rows. Nothing is equal to a null, not even another null. Nothing is inequal to a null either. This means that the `TEXT` rows are excluded because `WHERE field<>'TEXT'` is false, but the nulls are excluded because the result of `null<>'TEXT'` is actually null, which eventually evaluates to `false` when the where clause is choosing to include rows